# JavaScript: Inheritance in ECMAScript5

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

```
var A = function () {
    this.p1 = 2;
};
A.prototype.f1 = function () {
    return 7;
};
var B = function () {
    inherit(A, B);
};


function inherit(Child, Parent) {
    Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}

var b = new B();
console.log(b.p1); // get undefined here
```

I am new to JS, sorry for dump question. I would like to inherit `B` from `A`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Two things:

1. You're calling `inherit` **inside** `B`. You should be doing it outside.
2. Inside `B`, you should be calling `A`, e.g.

   ```
   A.call(this/*, other, args, here, if, needed*/);
   ```

   or

   ```
   A.apply(this, arguments);
   ```

   to pass on all of the arguments `B` received at runtime via the automatic `arguments` pseudo-array.

Like so:

```js
var A = function () {
    this.p1 = 2;
};
A.prototype.f1 = function () {
    return 7;
};
var B = function () {
    A.call(this);        // <==== Added
};
inherit(A, B);           // <==== Moved

function inherit(Child, Parent) {
    Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}

var b = new B();
console.log(b.p1); // get 2 here now
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! T.J. Crowder, could you please explain just in few words what happens when invoke `A.call(this);`

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ: When you do `A.call(x, y, z)`, it calls the function `A` in a way that makes `this` during `A`'s code be `x`, and then passing along `y` and `z` as arguments. It does basically what `foo.bar(y, z)` does (making `this` inside `bar` be `foo`), but without having to involve an object property expression. [More on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). (And `A.apply` is exactly like `A.call` except that if you want to pass arguments, you give them as an array-like object instead of individual args like you do wih `call`.)

Answer (score 2):

You're only calling `inherit()` after creating the instance of `B`.

You need to call `inherit()` statically, once, after defining both functions.

You also need to call `A` on your instance in `B`.

For more details on how to properly do inheritance, see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/).

Comment: *"You also need to call A on your instance in B."* Perhaps show how to do that, as it's non-trivial (well, trivial to *do*, but not trivial to know how to do it). (I'm sure the link covers it, but...)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call the base constructor. Also, it's enough if you inherit only once the classes.

```js
var A = function () {
    this.p1 = 2;
};
A.prototype.f1 = function () {
    return 7;
};
var B = function () {
    A.apply(this, arguments);
};
inherit(A, B);

function inherit(Child, Parent) {
    Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
    
}

var b = new B();
console.log(b.p1); // get undefined here
```